# No Set-Cookie header on Axios

Tags: vue.js, symfony, authentication, cookies, axios

I am using a Symfony API backend and want to authenticate by REST call via Axios inside a Vue App.

The authentication works fine when using POSTMAN. It stores a session cookie and resends it on subsequent requests.

However, when I use Axios it won't give me the Set-Cookie header.

**What I tried so far:**

- Adjusted CORS settings on Symfony backend (no CORS errors - all routes working)
- Set { withCredentials: true } as config parameter on Axios post request.

Symfony EventSubsriber for injecting CORS headers:

```
public function onKernelResponse(ResponseEvent $event)
{
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', [ 'Content-Type', 'Set-Cookie' ]);
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
}
```

Note that this is for local testing only.

Axios Request:

```
login(user, pw) {
    return axios.post(cfg.apiUrl + '/api/login', {
            username: user,
            password: pw
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
    );
}
```

Follow up request:

```
test() {
    return axios.get(cfg.apiUrl + '/api/test');
}
```

Could someone point out what I am still missing? Why do I get the header on POSTMAN, but not on Axios?

Comment: Are you trying to add a `Set-Cookie` header to a request? Do you know that this is supposed to be a _response_ header?

Comment: No, I'm not sending a Set-Cookie header on the request. All I am sending is in the above code snippet (edited).

Comment: Then why are you listing `Set-Cookie` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header?

Comment: You write: *when I use Axios it won't give me the `Set-Cookie` header.* Do you mean that you're trying to read the value of that header from the response that Axios gives you? If so, be aware that you cannot, because the Fetch standard disallows it. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name

Comment: Thanks for your effort @jub0bs. But, I've found the solution. I missed to also send withCredentials on follow up requests.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to also add the { withCredentials: true } in further requests. As it seems, it is not possible to read the Set-Cookie header via Axios, as @jub0bs pointed out.

The correct code for a follow-up request looks like:

```
test() {
    return axios.get(cfg.apiUrl + '/api/test', { withCredentials: true });
}
```